# SAS Date value check

Tags: date, datetime, sas

How to compare sas date JAN14 with other variable. I have used date1='JAN14'd but it is not working. What are the other options i can try? I have tried comparing with 'JAN14' also but again it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

That's only part of a date. You need to fully specify day, month and year, e.g. `'01JAN2014'd`